# How to implement selection sort?

Tags: java

I have the following code snippet..

```
public void selsort()
{
    int j=0,i,k; int low;
    for(k = 0; k < ele; k++)
    {
        for(i = j;i < ele; i++)
            if(a[i] < a[i+1])
                low = i;
        if(i!=j)
        {
            long temp=a[j];
            a[j]=a[i];
            a[i]=temp;
        }
        j++;
    }
}
```

I don't know why the above algorithm is not working properly.

What has to be modified to get it working properly?

Comment: I don't know either.. Because I don't know what your algorithm should do.

Comment: @MarounMaroun as the theory dictates that we have to find the minimum element in the entire array and swap it with the left most unsorted element(so first we have to exchange first minimum with the first element in the array and so on)...and this process has to be repeated till we get a sorted array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed your code

```
public void selsort() {
    int j = 0, i, k;
    int low;
    for (k = 0; k < ele; k++) {
        low = j;
        for (i = j; i < ele; i++)
            if (a[i] < a[low]) {
                low = i;
            }
        if (j != low) {
            int temp = a[j];
            a[j] = a[low];
            a[low] = temp;
        }
        j++;
    }
}
```

but can be used `k` insdead of `j`, and better have input params instead using class fields like `a` and `ele`